# Cannot reach Webmin neither /w Local nor Remote (Centos 7.2.1511)

Tags: centos, centos7, webmin

I installed Centos and everything in network (192.168.178.1/24), then I moved server to another network which has the exact same configuration (192.168.178.1/24). On the first network which has the same config, webmin was working without any problem, even after several restarts.

But right after I moved my server to new network, I cannot access to webmin anymore even though I can access Apache without any problem.

I have latest version of webmin and perl perl-Net-SSLeay openssl perl-IO-Tty.

Iptables (I use iptables instead of firewalld)

```
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)


Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   52 10201 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
   19   988 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10000
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
  132 13350 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    2   120 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    1    52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
  126 10254 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Webmin conf (some parts only, I tried both ssl=0 and ssl=1, no change)

```
port=10000
ssl=1
no_ssl2=1
no_ssl3=1
no_tls1=1
no_tls1_1=1
ssl_honorcipherorder=1
no_sslcompression=1
listen=10000
```

Apache & webmin & mariadb

```
Webmin (pid 2057) is running

httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-08-29 15:13:58 EEST; 10min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
 Main PID: 991 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 19; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─ 991 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2354 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2355 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2356 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2357 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2358 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2453 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─2454 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─2455 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-08-29 15:13:59 EEST; 21min ago
 Main PID: 1305 (mysqld_safe)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           ├─1305 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
           └─1814 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log -...

Aug 29 15:13:56 seyredelim.centos systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Aug 29 15:13:57 seyredelim.centos mysqld_safe[1305]: 160829 15:13:57 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
Aug 29 15:13:57 seyredelim.centos mysqld_safe[1305]: 160829 15:13:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Aug 29 15:13:59 seyredelim.centos systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
Aug 29 15:35:03 seyredelim.centos systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
```

When I try to login it using SSH with nc command

```
[root@**** supervisor]# nc -vw 3 192.168.178.178 10000
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 192.168.178.178:10000.
```

Everything seems okay, but funnily I still cannot connect to webmin for some reason. I dont have problem connecting to mysql, apache (80) or any other services using either local or remote.

Is there any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start using firewalld. The firewall you created yourself contains a number of problems. Firewalld will always create a firewall to spec.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you for suggestion. I tried firewalld too, I just installed iptables to see if I could solve the problem but no luck. I really don't see whats wrong with this config.